# Umbraco 7: Get the Umbraco.Field('"name") from Children pages in foreach

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I have installed Umbraco 7.1.5 using NuGet and VS2013. I have a MainMenu partial view that gets the document tree and populates the menu accordingly:

```
var homePage = CurrentPage.AncestorsOrSelf(1).First();
var menuItems = homePage.Children.Where("UmbracoNaviHide == false"); 

<ul class="nav">
<li class="@(CurrentPage.Url == "/" ? "current_page_item" : null)"><a class="Lvl1 home" href="/">Home</a></li>

@foreach (var item in menuItems)
{    
  <li class="@(CurrentPage.Id == item.Id ? "current_page_item" : null) Col1">
    <a class="lvl1 parent" href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>

    @{var subMenuItems = item.Children.Where("UmbracoNaviHide == false");}

    @if (subMenuItems.Count() > 0)
    {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var sub in subMenuItems)
            {
              ????  @Umbraco.Field("menuItemImage", recursive: true) ?????

                <li><a class="parent" href="@sub.Url">@sub.Name</a></li>
            }
        </ul>
    }
  </li>
}
</ul>
```

**Q**:How can I get the @Umbraco.Field("menuItemImage", recursive: true) (Upload type) for every sub menu item in the second foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GetPropertyValue from the IPublishedContent interface.

```
@foreach (var sub in subMenuItems)
{
    // will only work if image is mandatory, otherwise the inner value can be null.  
    // In that case you need to add an extra check
    var img = Umbraco.TypedMedia(sub.GetPropertyValue<string>("menuItemImage", recurse:true))
    <img src="@img.Url" alt="sub.Name" />
    <li><a class="parent" href="@sub.Url">@sub.Name</a></li>
 }
```

**Update**

Because you are using dynamics you are also able to do `@sub.menuItemImage`.  Because I don't like the dynamics too much, I regulary use `Model.Content` instead of `CurrentPage`.  Like that you will receive intellisense in visual studio due to `Model.Content` being strongly typed.

Comment: Thanks dampee! It also works if I pass `sub` as the first parameter: `@Umbraco.Field(sub, "menuItemImage", recursive: true)` returning the url string